# Is it possible to make PHP interpret a symbol as a $_GET in the URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, get

Sorry for the strange phrasing.

I'm working on a project to upgrade an University's website (this is not a school project, they hired the company I work for to do it).

We're working with wordpress, and the pages for professors are not single pages to be displayed directly, instead, they're shown in a modal on top of the main page.

To do that, I used `$_GET`, so when the user enters `www.example.com/?prof=isaac-newton` on their browser, they see the page at `www.example.com` with a modal on top of it,

this modal has the content of `www.example.com/professors/isaac-newton` in it.

The clients didn't like this very much, because their current system works with the user entering `www.example.com/~isaac-newton`, and they want to keep this standard.

Finally, my question is:

> Can I make PHP interpret something such as **`~isaac-newton`** in the url as **`?prof=isaac-newton`**? How?

Here is my current code which makes `?prof=` work:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['prof']))
{
    $prof = $_GET['prof'];
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#modal').modal({'remote' : 'http://www.example.com/professor/<?php echo $prof; ?>/'});
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: can't you just keep your solution, and just rewrite the incoming request for `www.exmple.org/~(....)` to `/?prof=$1` internally using a mod_rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file? This doesn't even require a PHP solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on apache for the webserver, you can add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\~([^/]*)$ /?prof=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I can't check right now, but I assume this works. Gonna try tomorrow when I'm at work again. 
Thanks, @dave . I'm pretty new to web development, so I'm sorry if that's a very basic thing.

Comment: Kiloku mentioned they are using wordpress so I don't think this would work without nuking the existing WP rewrite rules. It also looks like they're using pretty links so this is already happening! Unfortunately I don't have the time to answer, but I think the solution rests in adding a rewrite rule: `add_rewrite_rule('^~([^/]*)$','index.php?prof=$matches[1]','top');`

Comment: @TheManiac - there is no reason you couldn't use that rewrite rule with wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using URL rewriting technology to solve your problem. I don't know what kind of web server you're using but if it's [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) then take a look at the [Apache mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Also, have a look at this question: [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php). This should put you on the right track.